# Create new TextViews inside custom array adapter

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create Dynamic Text Views extracted from an array list inside a custom array Adapter. The array list data is returned from from JSON response. Since I don't know in advance how many items my array will contain, I can't create Text Views in XML, so they need to be created programatically.

The Text Views are added within a vertical linear layout as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> authors = currentBook.getAuthor();
    LinearLayout authorsList = convertView.findViewById(R.id.authors_list);

    for (int i =0; i < authors.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setText(authors.get(i));
        authorsList.addView(textView);
    }
```

When I run, some Text Views are created twice, and the data keeps changing as I scroll the list view.

I think there is an issue with inner working of list views that I don't understand, but cannot put my finger on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not using a ListView / RecycelerView with a recycled custom list item that contains a TexitView?

Comment: Try add: `authorsList.removeAllViews();` before the for-loop. Hope that helps!

Comment: @M.Zain I am beginner to android and I am just now learning about the RecycelerView. I managed to solve the problem. Thanks a lot for the comment.

Comment: @I_A_Mok This worked so well thank you very much

Comment: @ M. Elauzei... I am glad for that ... happy learning journey